# How to pass list of Files inside the model to API

Tags: angular, .net-core

I was trying to pass a model to API that has list of files inside the model, however, I received the error below:

[image]

Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'.

Here is my code to post the model to the API.

Please note that I have to used model because it contains data and attachment as an additional
input(Multiple attachments).

I used to submit a single file using formData, but since it is multiple and it has to be submitted inside the model, it's not working.

```
 submit(model: Model): Observable<any> {
        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var i in model.files) {
            new Blob([JSON.stringify({})], { type: 'application/json' });
            fd.append('model', model.files[i]);
        }
        return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/API/Submit`, model, this.httpOptions);
    }
```

Comment: just a recommendation, I strongly suggest using `const` or `let`, do not use  `var`.